# Paperback near-future sci-fi novel in which there is an ice age coming

Tags: story-identification, novel

Paperback near-future novel in which there is an ice age coming, and rich people and politicians prepare an underground facility and go into cryogenic suspension for thousands of years. After they fall alseep, the protagonist and his team break in and take their place. They may have had mech battle suits.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Some more information would be useful: When did you read the book? In what language? Was it new then? Do you remember where it took place (US, UK, elsewehere)? Any names? Were there any women on the team? Anything about the cover...

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be talking about [*Time of the Great Freeze*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/449322.Time_of_the_Great_Freeze) (1964), by Robert Silverberg.

> For centuries, men had lived miles beneath the ground in order to survive the great Ice Block that had submerged the earth. In an attempt to resume human contact, Jim Barnes, his father and several other daring men emerge from a subterranean New York to cross the frozen Atlantic. Coping bravely with problems of food and shelter, the fury of snowstorm and the attacks of wild beasts, and the strange, savage men who roam the Earth's ice crust, they finally reach London, only to find an angry and distrustful mob. Jim's pivotal role in establishing trust and unity is revealed in a suspenseful and thrilling climax.

Comment: *Time of the Great Freeze* is set centuries after the new Ice Age began. The question seems to be asking about a story that was set just as people could see a new Ice Age was *beginning,* with one group trying to seize control of another group's underground facility in which they planned to wait it out in cryogenic suspension until things would someday warm up again.

Comment: The words suspended and animation don't appear in the answer's story.

Comment: One of them "The Survivalist" books maybe. There was a lot IIRC

Answer (score -1):

I think I read this! The location where the cryogenic was taking place was the Driftless area of Wisconsin. My mind is telling me it was called something like The Pegasus Project.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2116870?

Comment: I'm kind of torn. I'm a big fan of partial answers, but this feels more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I don't think this it [In fifteen thousand years, humanity has never found evidence for alien life, but Ronda gets tasked with checking out a possible transmission.](http://www.rocketstackrank.com/2017/01/The-Pegasus-Project-Jack-McDevitt.html)